# How to avoid mute when adding new call

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, calls, phone-app

I'm on Android 4.2.1.

During a call, tapping 'Add call', automatically mutes the current call. I find it very annoying, mostly because usually when I want to add a call it's because I want to make a conference call.
Further more, sometimes I'm asking someone for a friend's number, when starting to type the number I'm muted, and the first one goes "hey, you're writing?". Very annoying.

Anyway is there a way to disable this annoying behavior?